# react-native-user-inactivity - How to prolong timeForInactivity prop value

Tags: react-native

I create a simple screen which has only a button and be able to detect user inactivity after 2 minutes.I wrap my screen with  *UserInactivity* component from a library named [react-native-user-inactivity](https://github.com/jkomyno/react-native-user-inactivity)  I'm trying to reset ***timeForInactivity*** prop by pressing the button(i.e. whenever I press the button within 2 minutes before  the inactivity will be detected, the timeForInactivity should be reset to 0 and start counting up to 2 minutes again)

below is my code to archive the result I want but it doesn't work.

```
const inactiveTime = 2*(60*1000)
export function SimpleScreen(){
const [inactiveTimer,setInactiveTimer] = useState(inactiveTime)

 const resetInactiveTime = () =>{
     setInactiveTimer(inactiveTime)
 }
 return(
   <UserInactivity
      timeForInactivity={inactiveTimer}  
   >
      <View>

        <Button onPress={resetInactiveTime}/>

      </View>

   <UserInactivity>
 )
}
```

setInactiveTimer gets called but timeForInactivity doesn't seem to receive the new timer from setInactiveTimer.It keeps counting down the old one.
Any ideas, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using the same reference value, to update the state and reflect the changes, you should change Its reference too. Try below

```
 const resetInactiveTime = () =>{
     setInactiveTimer(2*(60*1000)); // try this way
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `react-native-inactivity` module for this purpose. By using this module you can reset the timer easily. You can set loop and the timer will reset/restart automatically.

```js
import ReactNativeInactivity from "react-native-inactivity";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ReactNativeInactivity
        isActive={true}
        onInactive={() => {//Do something when the view will be inactive}}
        timeForInactivity={2*(60*1000)} //This should be in ms
        loop={true} // Will reset/restart automatically after expires
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <YOUR_AUTHENTICATED_NAVIGATOR_HERE/>
      </ReactNativeInactivity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also manage other props according to your requirement.

If this solution helped you just thumbs up and give me a star at repository.
For more refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inactivity